# Pick all rows with any value in common with numbers in a array (selected row)

Tags: matlab

I have `T_Elements` file (12732x9 double) among which I have selected a specific row using:

```
MaxValueElement_Nodes=T_ELEMENTS(IdxinT_Elements,y1:end);
```

Now I want to get all rows in `T_Elements` file which have any value in common with numbers in `MaxValueElement_Nodes` array (selected row).

I have tried using `unique`, `ismember` but I can't find syntax in MATLAB to get rows with any value common with my selected row.

Comment: Please show what you have tried in the form of a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

This should work on recent versions of Matlab:

```
T_ELEMENTS( any( T_ELEMENTS == MaxValueElement_Nodes, 2 ), : )
```

if you get an error when evaluating `T_ELEMENTS == MaxValueElement_Nodes` that means you are likely using an older version which did not have implicit expansion, in which case you can always use bsxfun as in:

```
T_ELEMENTS( any( bsxfun( @eq, T_ELEMENTS, MaxValueElement_Nodes ), 2 ), : )
```